# How do I check for the existence of multiple folders and remove them?

Tags: python

I am trying to search for the existence of multiple folders, and if they exist, to delete them. At the moment, the following code works to find and delete a single folder titled "runtime" with *myfile_path* defined earlier.

```
if os.path.exists(myfile_path + "/runtime"):
    shutil.rmtree(myfile_path + "/runtime")
```

Rather than repeat these two lines of code for each folder I want to search and delete, is there a cleaner concise way of achieving that? For simplicity, lets say I want to search and delete three folders with all their contents:

- FolderA
- JunkB
- DirectoryC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) of all folders you want to remove and then [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) through them, doing the same operation with different values.

```py
junk_folders = ['FolderA', 'JunkB', 'DirectoryC']

for folder in junk_folders:
    if os.path.exists(myfile_path + "/" + folder):
        shutil.rmtree(myfile_path + "/" + folder)
```

Comment: it seems to not like the syntax for the following: for folder in junk_folders, where junk_folders is a list of the folders I wish to have deleted.

Comment: Can you please provide with the full error code you're getting? It sounds like you're doing something wrong. Make sure that it is `myfile_path + "/" + folder` and not `myfile_path + "/" + junk_folders`  inside the loop.

Comment: I apologize, I see now I missed a colon. The code works now! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, great you figured it out :)